# Como calcular PI com "n" casas decimais em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, matemática

Usando o objeto `Math` do JavaScript, eu consigo retornar um valor PI com casas decimais fixas, exemplo:

```
Math.PI //3.141592653589793
```

Mas e no caso de eu precisar *(sim, bem incomum)* calcular o mesmo com mais casas decimais, existe alguma outra forma de definir um número de casas decimais? Exemplo:

```
Math.pi(300) //retornaria com precisão de 300 casas decimais, etc.
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você precisa é de uma biblioteca de manipulação de números decimais de precisão arbitrária. Um `double` (formato numérico usado por JavaScript para o tipo `Number`) tem precisão de no máximo umas 15 casas decimais (`floor(log10(2^53))`), de modo que se você precisa fazer qualquer conta envolvendo mais casas que isso, é necessário representar esses números de alguma outra forma.

(e você *quer* fazer contas com π, certo? Pois se fosse só questão de exibi-lo, uma string pré-populada com seu valor bastaria...)

Uma vez escolhida uma biblioteca, você tem duas opções:

1. Para se usar na prática, é preferível [obter o valor de π de algum lugar](http://www.eveandersson.com/pi/digits/1000000) em vez de calculá-lo. Uma string de 300 bytes não traz um *overhead* tão grande pro seu sistema... (em especial pelo código a mais que você teria que colocar para fazer seu cálculo)
2. Se for mesmo necessário (ou desejável, por exemplo para fins de estudo) calcular você mesmo, há diversas fórmulas que convergem para π. Uma delas (a primeira sugestão da [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51626/215)) é `π = 48*arctan(1/18) + 32*arctan(1/57) − 20*arctan(1/239)`, onde o arco tangente pode ser calculado por meio de uma série infinita. [Outras séries e/ou expressões infinitas](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~huberty/math5337/groupe/expresspi.html) também convergem para π.

Não sei dizer qual é a melhor (nem qual o melhor critério para definir "a melhor"), então vou dar um exemplo usando o arco seno, pois me parece bem fácil de calcular:

```
                1 * x^3   1 * 3 * x^5   1 * 3 * 5 * x^7
arcsin(x) = x + ------- + ----------- + --------------- + ...
                2 * 3     2 * 4 * 5     2 * 4 * 6 * 7

arcsin(1/2) = π/6
```

Usando a biblioteca [javascript-bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum):

```
var pi = new BigNumber("3", precisao + 5); // Começa com 3 (6*x, x == 1/2)
var antigo = new BigNumber("0", precisao + 5);

var numerador = new BigNumber("6", precisao + 5); // O numerador da próxima parcela
var denominador = new BigNumber("1", precisao + 5); // Parte do denominador (comum)
var potencia2 = new BigNumber("2", precisao + 5); // Outra parte (variável)

var indice = 1; // Qual parcela está sendo acrescentada

function passo() {
  if ( pi.compare(antigo) == 0 ) // Se o valor não mudou, já convergiu
    return;

  antigo = pi; // Salva o valor antigo

  numerador = numerador.multiply(indice);
  denominador = denominador.multiply(indice+1);
  potencia2 = potencia2.multiply(4);

  // Acrescenta a próxima parcela na série
  var parcela = numerador.divide(denominador).divide(indice+2).divide(potencia2);
  pi = pi.add(parcela);

  indice += 2
  setTimeout(passo, 0); // Executa o próximo passo (assíncrono)
}
passo(); // Começa
```

```js
//+ Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
//@ http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber [rev. #4]

BigNumber = function(n, p, r){
    var o = this, i;
    if(n instanceof BigNumber){
        for(i in {precision: 0, roundType: 0, _s: 0, _f: 0}) o[i] = n[i];
        o._d = n._d.slice();
        return;
    }
    o.precision = isNaN(p = Math.abs(p)) ? BigNumber.defaultPrecision : p;
    o.roundType = isNaN(r = Math.abs(r)) ? BigNumber.defaultRoundType : r;
    o._s = (n += "").charAt(0) == "-";
    o._f = ((n = n.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "").split(".", 2))[0] = n[0].replace(/^0+/, "") || "0").length;
    for(i = (n = o._d = (n.join("") || "0").split("")).length; i; n[--i] = +n[i]);
    o.round();
};
with({$: BigNumber, o: BigNumber.prototype}){
    $.ROUND_HALF_EVEN = ($.ROUND_HALF_DOWN = ($.ROUND_HALF_UP = ($.ROUND_FLOOR = ($.ROUND_CEIL = ($.ROUND_DOWN = ($.ROUND_UP = 0) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1;
    $.defaultPrecision = 40;
    $.defaultRoundType = $.ROUND_HALF_UP;
    o.add = function(n){
        if(this._s != (n = new BigNumber(n))._s)
            return n._s ^= 1, this.subtract(n);
        var o = new BigNumber(this), a = o._d, b = n._d, la = o._f,
        lb = n._f, n = Math.max(la, lb), i, r;
        la != lb && ((lb = la - lb) > 0 ? o._zeroes(b, lb, 1) : o._zeroes(a, -lb, 1));
        i = (la = a.length) == (lb = b.length) ? a.length : ((lb = la - lb) > 0 ? o._zeroes(b, lb) : o._zeroes(a, -lb)).length;
        for(r = 0; i; r = (a[--i] = a[i] + b[i] + r) / 10 >>> 0, a[i] %= 10);
        return r && ++n && a.unshift(r), o._f = n, o.round();
    };
    o.subtract = function(n){
        if(this._s != (n = new BigNumber(n))._s)
            return n._s ^= 1, this.add(n);
        var o = new BigNumber(this), c = o.abs().compare(n.abs()) + 1, a = c ? o : n, b = c ? n : o, la = a._f, lb = b._f, d = la, i, j;
        a = a._d, b = b._d, la != lb && ((lb = la - lb) > 0 ? o._zeroes(b, lb, 1) : o._zeroes(a, -lb, 1));
        for(i = (la = a.length) == (lb = b.length) ? a.length : ((lb = la - lb) > 0 ? o._zeroes(b, lb) : o._zeroes(a, -lb)).length; i;){
            if(a[--i] < b[i]){
                for(j = i; j && !a[--j]; a[j] = 9);
                --a[j], a[i] += 10;
            }
            b[i] = a[i] - b[i];
        }
        return c || (o._s ^= 1), o._f = d, o._d = b, o.round();
    };
    o.multiply = function(n){
        var o = new BigNumber(this), r = o._d.length >= (n = new BigNumber(n))._d.length, a = (r ? o : n)._d,
        b = (r ? n : o)._d, la = a.length, lb = b.length, x = new BigNumber, i, j, s;
        for(i = lb; i; r && s.unshift(r), x.set(x.add(new BigNumber(s.join("")))))
            for(s = (new Array(lb - --i)).join("0").split(""), r = 0, j = la; j; r += a[--j] * b[i], s.unshift(r % 10), r = (r / 10) >>> 0);
        return o._s = o._s != n._s, o._f = ((r = la + lb - o._f - n._f) >= (j = (o._d = x._d).length) ? this._zeroes(o._d, r - j + 1, 1).length : j) - r, o.round();
    };
    o.divide = function(n){
        if((n = new BigNumber(n)) == "0")
            throw new Error("Division by 0");
        else if(this == "0")
            return new BigNumber;
        var o = new BigNumber(this), a = o._d, b = n._d, la = a.length - o._f,
        lb = b.length - n._f, r = new BigNumber, i = 0, j, s, l, f = 1, c = 0, e = 0;
        r._s = o._s != n._s, r.precision = Math.max(o.precision, n.precision),
        r._f = +r._d.pop(), la != lb && o._zeroes(la > lb ? b : a, Math.abs(la - lb));
        n._f = b.length, b = n, b._s = false, b = b.round();
        for(n = new BigNumber; a[0] == "0"; a.shift());
        out:
        do{
            for(l = c = 0, n == "0" && (n._d = [], n._f = 0); i < a.length && n.compare(b) == -1; ++i){
                (l = i + 1 == a.length, (!f && ++c > 1 || (e = l && n == "0" && a[i] == "0")))
                && (r._f == r._d.length && ++r._f, r._d.push(0));
                (a[i] == "0" && n == "0") || (n._d.push(a[i]), ++n._f);
                if(e)
                    break out;
                if((l && n.compare(b) == -1 && (r._f == r._d.length && ++r._f, 1)) || (l = 0))
                    while(r._d.push(0), n._d.push(0), ++n._f, n.compare(b) == -1);
            }
            if(f = 0, n.compare(b) == -1 && !(l = 0))
                while(l ? r._d.push(0) : l = 1, n._d.push(0), ++n._f, n.compare(b) == -1);
            for(s = new BigNumber, j = 0; n.compare(y = s.add(b)) + 1 && ++j; s.set(y));
            n.set(n.subtract(s)), !l && r._f == r._d.length && ++r._f, r._d.push(j);
        }
        while((i < a.length || n != "0") && (r._d.length - r._f) <= r.precision);
        return r.round();
    };
    o.mod = function(n){
        return this.subtract(this.divide(n).intPart().multiply(n));
    };
    o.pow = function(n){
        var o = new BigNumber(this), i;
        if((n = (new BigNumber(n)).intPart()) == 0) return o.set(1);
        for(i = Math.abs(n); --i; o.set(o.multiply(this)));
        return n < 0 ? o.set((new BigNumber(1)).divide(o)) : o;
    };
    o.set = function(n){
        return this.constructor(n), this;
    };
    o.compare = function(n){
        var a = this, la = this._f, b = new BigNumber(n), lb = b._f, r = [-1, 1], i, l;
        if(a._s != b._s)
            return a._s ? -1 : 1;
        if(la != lb)
            return r[(la > lb) ^ a._s];
        for(la = (a = a._d).length, lb = (b = b._d).length, i = -1, l = Math.min(la, lb); ++i < l;)
            if(a[i] != b[i])
                return r[(a[i] > b[i]) ^ a._s];
        return la != lb ? r[(la > lb) ^ a._s] : 0;
    };
    o.negate = function(){
        var n = new BigNumber(this); return n._s ^= 1, n;
    };
    o.abs = function(){
        var n = new BigNumber(this); return n._s = 0, n;
    };
    o.intPart = function(){
        return new BigNumber((this._s ? "-" : "") + (this._d.slice(0, this._f).join("") || "0"));
    };
    o.valueOf = o.toString = function(){
        var o = this;
        return (o._s ? "-" : "") + (o._d.slice(0, o._f).join("") || "0") + (o._f != o._d.length ? "." + o._d.slice(o._f).join("") : "");
    };
    o._zeroes = function(n, l, t){
        var s = ["push", "unshift"][t || 0];
        for(++l; --l;  n[s](0));
        return n;
    };
    o.round = function(){
        if("_rounding" in this) return this;
        var $ = BigNumber, r = this.roundType, b = this._d, d, p, n, x;
        for(this._rounding = true; this._f > 1 && !b[0]; --this._f, b.shift());
        for(d = this._f, p = this.precision + d, n = b[p]; b.length > d && !b[b.length -1]; b.pop());
        x = (this._s ? "-" : "") + (p - d ? "0." + this._zeroes([], p - d - 1).join("") : "") + 1;
        if(b.length > p){
            n && (r == $.DOWN ? false : r == $.UP ? true : r == $.CEIL ? !this._s
            : r == $.FLOOR ? this._s : r == $.HALF_UP ? n >= 5 : r == $.HALF_DOWN ? n > 5
            : r == $.HALF_EVEN ? n >= 5 && b[p - 1] & 1 : false) && this.add(x);
            b.splice(p, b.length - p);
        }
        return delete this._rounding, this;
    };
}

var continuar = true;
document.getElementById("calcular").onclick = function() {
    var precisao = parseInt(document.getElementById("precisao").value, 10);

    var pi = new BigNumber("3", precisao + 5);
    var antigo = new BigNumber("0", precisao + 5);

    var numerador = new BigNumber("6", precisao + 5);
    var denominador = new BigNumber("1", precisao + 5);
    var potencia2 = new BigNumber("2", precisao + 5);
  
    var indice = 1;
    function passo() {
      if ( pi.compare(antigo) == 0 || !continuar )
        return;
      
      antigo = pi;
      
      numerador = numerador.multiply(indice);
      denominador = denominador.multiply(indice+1);
      potencia2 = potencia2.multiply(4);
      
      var parcela = numerador.divide(denominador).divide(indice+2).divide(potencia2);
      pi = pi.add(parcela);
      
      indice += 2
      atualizar();
      
      setTimeout(passo, 0);
    }
  
    continuar = true;
    passo();

  function atualizar() {
    var str1 = "" + pi;
    var str2 = "" + antigo;
    var saida = "<strong>";
    var igual = true;
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < precisao ; i++ ) {
      if ( igual && str1[i] != str2[i] ) {
        igual = false;
        saida += "</strong>"
      }
      saida += str1[i];
    }
    document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML = saida;
  }    
};

document.getElementById("parar").onclick = function() {
    continuar = false;
};
```

```html
Precisão: <input id="precisao" type="number" value="70"/>
<button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
<button id="parar">Parar</button>
<p id="saida"></p>
```

No exemplo de código acima, o `precisao + 5` é para dar uma margem razoável para que a convergência aconteça (do contrário, as parcelas menores serão arredondadas pra zero e não entrarão na série). Coloquei 70 casas decimais, pois demora muito pra convergir no caso de 300 (se você tiver paciência de esperar, deve funcionar, entretanto).

Comment: Ótima resposta! Não tinha conhecimento dessa possibilidade, e o trecho de código calculando é perfeitamente auto-explicativo, incrível.

Answer (score 6):

Certamente teria que criar um algoritmo próprio e não é algo tão simples.

Achei [esse código](http://cosinekitty.com/pi.html). Como não há licença explícita não sei se posso trazer para cá.

[Outro código](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/longnumPiMachin.htm) que talvez possa ser usado como referência.

Se eu achar mais alguma coisa que possa melhorar a resposta eu postarei aqui.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

## Pi One-liner

Abaixo alguns one-liner usando diversas linguagens... (quase todos roubados! de várias fontes)

bash+**bc** (bc=calculadora unix)(`tang(π/4)=1` portanto `4 x arcotang(1)= 4 x π/4= π`)

```
bc -l <<< "scale=1000; 4*a(1)"
```

**internet**-based...

```
curl --silent http://www.angio.net/pi/digits/pi1000000.txt | cut -c1-3000
```

**perl**

```
perl -Mbignum=bpi -le 'print bpi(100)'
```

**python**

```
python -c "from mpmath import mp;mp.dps=500;print mp.pi"
```

de certeza que algum **include** terá o PI com algumas casas...

```
grep -ohP '3.14\d{30,}' /usr/include/*.h
```

ou mesmo escolher o PI dos includes mais completo

```
grep -rohP '3\.14\d*' /usr/include | awk 'length > length(pi){pi=$0}  END{print pi}'
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651
```

Se tiverem o **LaTeX** instalado... (convém ser a versão mais recente :)

```
tex --version | head -1 | cut -f2 -d' '
```

Comment: Já que foram "*quase todos roubados! de várias fontes*", por que não cita essas fontes?

Comment: @renan, agora é que tu me tramaste! Não sei... http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-one-liners-explained-part-three/; isto nasceu de uma discussão de café entre amigos -- É mais fácil a minha "não roubada" foi a dos includes (mas mesmo essa de certeza que já alguem se lembrou antes). Os monossílabos entre o código são meus...