# Tipo de variável para cálculos precisos (JAVA)

Tags: java, matemática

Qual o melhor tipo de váriavel para cálculos muito precisos ?

> Já usei double e BigDecimal e os arredondamentos estão divergindo
>   muito no resultado final.

Comment: Pra aplicação financeira o melhor é o BigDecimal ou então pra demais aplicações o Double serve. É isso que busca?

Comment: Estou usando bigDecimal e tá dando uma margem de erro no arrendodamento não aceitável.. :|

Comment: Até então, pelo meu pouco conhecimento, a melhor variável realmente é a BigDecimal. Talvez o cálculo esteja sendo efetuado de forma errada?

Você já tentou usar o Double ou a aplicação realmente é financeira e trabalha com números maiores que o Double possa suportar?

Comment: Se for cálculo para moeda,  existe a Moneta que é implementação da  JSR 354(Money API) -  http://javamoney.github.io/ri.html, tem também o Joda Money - http://www.joda.org/joda-money/. Agora para cálculos matemáticos tem a  Commons Math - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/

Comment: não é pra moeda.

Comment: Com o Lucas essa é a quarta pessoa que te diz que o seu problema não é o `BigDecimal` (estou usando `BigDecimal` para problemas onde é inaceitável erros antes da trigésima casa, e isso não chega nem perto de ser um caso de uso tão extremo). O único problema com o `BigDecimal` é que a API dele é um tanto quanto *verbose*, geralmente eu faço cálculos complicados em Scala que tem uma API mais rica. Em relação à precisão, mesmo que você use uma API científica com um tipo Decimal alternativo, ela não vai conseguir corrigir suas entradas.

Comment: Mostre seu código para assim permitir uma ajuda.

Comment: Suspendi a resposta como *"não pode ser reproduzido"* porque não existe problema de precisão com `BigDecimal` e nem sérios problemas com `double. Como já se percebeu, o problema do AP são dados externos, as entradas do programa. A única resposta possível sem o contexto é a que já existe: *"o tipo não vai resolveu seu problema"*.

Answer (score 4):

Nenhum tipo de dado vai resolver pra você os problemas de precisão, seja ponto flutuante (`double`), ponto fixo (`BigDecimal`) ou qualquer outro. Você precisa identificar em que sentido os seus cálculos estão acumulando erros, e tentar adotar medidas para contorná-los.

- Você está comparando dados de grandezas muito diferentes? (ex.: somar um número muito grande e um muito pequeno) Se for esse o caso, o ponto flutuante pode perder precisão, e o jeito seria usar um `BigDecimal` com número de dígitos significativos suficientes para representar toda a gama de números com os quais você está lidando.
- Você está fazendo uma sequência muito longa de cálculos, usando a representação mínima necessária para os números com os quais está lidando? Se for isso, os pequenos erros de arredondamento em cada cálculo individual acabam se acumulando, dando uma grande diferença no final. Algumas soluções possíveis seriam:

  - Aumentar o número de dígitos significativos. Se suas entradas são números com 5 casas decimais, por exemplo, aumente-as pra 10. Não existe uma regra pra isso, apenas veja o quão longa é sua sequência de cálculos e determine qual o maior erro que poderá ser propagado ao final dessa sequência.

    (um exemplo de solução via mais dígitos: [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51654/215) eu precisei calcular PI através de uma série. Usar o número exato de dígitos trouxe o resultado errado, porque as contribuições individuais dos termos da série ficavam truncados. Foi necessário acrescentar mais dígitos aos números durante o cálculo, ainda que no resultado final esses dígitos fossem descartados)
  - Usar intervalos em vez de simples números. Essa técnica (que se me recordo bem foi proposta por Knuth) consiste em pegar o resultado de uma operação levando em conta tanto seu teto quanto seu piso (em relação à precisão desejada), e ao aplicar a próxima operação, combinar teto-teto, piso-piso, piso-teto e teto-piso, usando o máximo e o mínimo encontrado como o novo intervalo. Repetir para cada operação, e ao final fazer a média do intervalo resultante (e ainda de quebra você tem uma margem de erro).